# Undefined variable: db_selected in C:\wamp\www\demo.php on line 14

Tags: php, database, database-connection

Im just learning about linking databases and php. I have a database called forms1 that i created with a table named "demo" in the "demo" table i have two forms, ID and input1. when I test my demo.php i get the following error,

Notice: Undefined variable: db_selected in C:\wamp\www\demo.php on line 13
Call Stack

## Time    Memory  Function    Location

1   0.0006  250416  {main}( )   ..\demo.php:0
can't useforms1:

Here is my php

---

```
    <?php
      define('DB_NAME', 'forms1');
      define('DB_USER', 'root');
      define('DB_PASSWORD', '');
      define('DB_HOST', 'localhost');

      $link = mysql_connect(DB_HOST, DB_USER, DB_PASSWORD);

      if (!$link) {
  die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error());
  }
  $db_seleccted = mysql_select_db(DB_NAME, $link);
      if (!$db_selected) {
  die('can\'t use' . DB_NAME . ': ' . mysql_error());
  }
     echo 'Connected Successfully';
      mysql_close();
    ?>
```

Does anyone have an idea what may be the problem?

Comment: Did you read your own code? Or first error case you came here to get help?

There is $db_seleccted and $db_selected in the same code.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about a spelling mistake.

Answer (score 1):

You spelled your variable incorrectly:

```
$db_seleccted = mysql_select_db(DB_NAME, $link); <-- HERE
```

Notice the double "c". Easy fix:

```
$db_selected = mysql_select_db(DB_NAME, $link);
```

Comment: So, make community wikis when you're too ashamed to get reputation from answering this kind of question? Interesting, I should try that as well.

Comment: Or, change to `if (!$db_seleccted)` ;-) There's more than one way to get that Waskiwee Wabbit!

Comment: wow that was an easy fix, crazy how one little thing blows the page up. Thanks!